# How do I wait for all Promises to finish before executuing ABCD function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am creating a new Promise every time I am requesting distance from Google API. I want all Promises to resolve and then call ABCD function? Right now it calls ABCD function right away.

```
async function RunBookings(Records) {
  for (var k = 0; k < gDestinationsArray.length; k++) {
    console.log('k' + k);
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('new Promise');
      var DistanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      DistanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: gOriginsArray[k],
        destinations: gDestinationsArray[k],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          console.log(response);
          var results = response.rows[0].elements; //console.log(results );
          for (var l = 0; l < results.length; l++) {
            gDistanceArray.push(results[l].distance.text);
          }
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('Good promise');
          }, 10000);
        } else if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          console.log('OVER_QUERY_LIMIT');
          console.log(response);
          console.log(status);
          reject(Error("Bad promise"));
        } else {
          console.log('BAD');
          console.log(response);
          console.log(status);
          reject(new Error("Bad promise"));
        }
      });
    });
    let result = await promise;
  }
}

function ABCD() {

}

RunBookings(Records);
ABCD();
```

Comment: `RunBookings(Records).finally(ABCD)` would work.

Comment: Seems like that you arent returning the response of the promise itself out of the for loop of the function. unless I am missing something. when you call runbookings it just processes information. nothing is being returned

Comment: @divyanshch [`async function`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always implicitly return a promise.

Comment: that makes sense, even in this case though there is nothing returned as a value, so you would just get a void promise returned

Comment: That is correct, but it's still useful as an indication that the processing is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should wait for all the promises with **Promise.all(promises)**

```
function RunBookings(Records) {
  const promises = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < gDestinationsArray.length; k++) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    ..... your code....

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  return promises;
}

function ABCD() {
}


Promise.all(RunBookings(Records))
   .then( val => {
       ABCD();
   });
```

or with async/await

```
async function RunBookings(Records) {
  const promises = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < gDestinationsArray.length; k++) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    ..... your code....

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  return promises;
}

function ABCD() {
}


let result = await RunBookings(Records);
ABCD();
```

or if you want return a single promise

```
async function RunBookings(Records) {
  await Promise.all(gDestinationArray.map(async (gDestination) => {
           ............
  }));
}

RunBookings(Records);
ABCD();
```

Comment: If you're going to rewrite it like that, `RunBookings(Records)` should be returning `Promise.all(gDestinationsArray.map((destination, k) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... })))`.

Comment: _Promise.all(promises)_ wait for end of all promise on the array _promises_, the you could execute ABCD(). RunBookings(Records) could only returns an array of promises to work with my solution.

Comment: It's more canonical for the asynchronous function to return the aggregate promise rather than an array of promises. The consuming code should not have to be responsible for constructing the aggregate promise from the array is what I'm saying.

Comment: Yes, i just tried in my IDE something like your first reply, and it works. Don't forget to put _await_ before _Promise.all_.

Comment: Your last function is wrong. Don't use `await`, use _`return`_, and you'd still have to `await RunBookings(Recods);` or use Bergi's solution.

Answer (score 1):

`RunBookings` is an `async function` and therefore returns a promise (it doesn't block!), therefore use

```
RunBookings(Records).then(ABCD);
```